# C++ Qt - Can QSignalMapper be cleared and re-used?

Tags: qt

Consider a card game. Cards are drawn from a deck and displayed on screen. The cards are clickable, and lead to the same effect, so the use of `QSignalMapper` was obvious.

Now, consider discarding those cards, to draw new ones.

Is there a way to clear `QSignalMapper`, or is `QSignalMapper` automatically cleared when an object is removed from UI?

I thought about `[QSignalMapper::removeMappings][1] ( QObject * sender )` but I am unsure about what 'sender' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` parameter is the same object that you gave as the first parameter to `setMapping()`

Additionally, it is worth noting what the documentation has to say under `removeMappings()`:

> This is done automatically when mapped objects are destroyed.

So if you're destroying objects that you've given to a `SignalMapper`, it will clean itself up when those objects are deleted.

Comment: OH! I read that too fast and understood "when signal mapper is destroy".